# Change class name when another div is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a "parent" div and a "child" div, but in reality they are not. Basically, what I would like to do is change the class name of the "parent" div when the "child" is clicked.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div [style.display]="this.menuofrole.start == true ? 'block' : 'none'" class="item"
        (click)="displayStuff($event, this.Org[0],1)">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-child"></i>Example
    </div>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let content of this.Org">
        <div class="orgDropdown" (click)="displayStuff($event, content,1)">
            <a class="">{{content.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

The function that I use to change the div class. It works but I would like to create another function where the class of the "parent" div changes. The function below changes the class of the clicked div.

```
highlightClickedParentItem(event) {
  var parents = event.target.closest(".left").parentElement;
  var children = parents.querySelectorAll('.item')

  var count = children.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    children[i].className = "item";
  }
  // checked clicked item icon
  var targetParents = event.target.closest(".dropdown");
  var children2 = targetParents.querySelectorAll('.item');

  var count = children2.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    children2[i].className = "item active";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass), on clicking just trigger a function and change variable like follows

**In HTML**

```
<div [ngClass]="{'parent-class':item,'child-class':!item}">parent
  <div  (click)="childClick()">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

**In Component**

```
item:boolean=true

childClick(){
  this.item=false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example [on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szypnh)
Basically the thing is in ngClass directive and ability to pass arguments from html

```
export class AppComponent  {
  cssClass: string;
  active: boolean;

  changeClass(clss: string): void {
    this.cssClass = clss;
    this.active = !this.active;
  }
}
```

and in your html:

```
<div [ngClass]="cssClass" [class.active]="active">PARENT</div>
<div (click)="changeClass('new-class')">CLICK 1</div>
<div (click)="changeClass('new-class2')">CLICK 2</div>
```

to make sure add the css like that(just for example)

```
.new-class {
  background: cyan
}
.new-class2 {
  background:green;
}
```

**EDIT: added 'active' class toggle**

Comment: hi, i would like to add the "active" state to the parent class. how would i be able to achieve that?